# Excel In cell formula Number of surveys administered

Tags: excel-formula

Good Afternoon,

I have an excel sheet that records encounters with community residents by name and date.  During each encounter a brief survey is also administered.  I want to track changes to these survey questions by name over time.  Is there any way to do this with in cell formulas?  Here's an example of the table I have in mind:

```
| Name         | Date             | Q1 | Q2 | Stress | Survey Number |
|              |                  |    |    |        | (calculated)  |
|--------------|------------------|----|----|--------|---------------|
| Steve Rogers | 5/1/2018         | y  | y  | 5      | 1             |
| Steve Rogers | 5/2/2018         | y  | y  | 6      | 2             |
| Tony Stark   | 5/1/2018         | n  | n  | 10     | 1             |
| Nick Fury    | 5/1/2018         | n  | y  | 8      | 1             |
| Nick Fury    | 5/2/2018         | y  | y  | 5      | 2             |
| Tony Stark   | 5/2/2018         | y  | n  | 8      | 2             |
| Tony Stark   | 5/3/2018         | n  | n  | 4      | 3             |
```

I want to calculate the survey number by referencing the name and the date.  I have no idea where to start, honestly.  Is this even possible using an in-cell reference?

Comment: Unclear; do you want the row number given a specific name and a specific date??...................  **please update your question with a specific example of your desired output.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<=" & B2)
```

Put that in F2 and copy/drag down.

[image]

Comment: Your formula works properly if the table is listed in chronological order by date.  That may not always be the case.  Is there a way to take the correctly generate the survey number even if the dates are out of order?  If not, that's fine, thanks for your solution!

Comment: @DustinBurns will the surveys always have different days per person or can the same person take two or more surveys in one day?

Comment: They will always have different days per person

Comment: Added level of complexity:  There are times when a resident hasn't completed a survey, but they are still entered into the table.  I've corrected the formula to account for this:

=IF(OR(C2 <> "", D2 <> "",E2 <> ""), COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, "<=" & B2), "")

That's not working.  I need it to skip those dates where there was no survey administered.  Any ideas?

Comment: That is a new question, please ask one with new data set that shows what you are wanting.